# SampleCurrencyData.txt Como obtenerlo

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Hola estoy siguiendo la serie de tutoriales de **SSIS How to Create an ETL Package** de Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services en Visual Studio pero hay una parte de la cual no he podido pasar y es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, me pide que en la parte del botón browse, busque en mi sistema el archivo de nombre `SampleCurrencyData.txt` el cual no existe en mis sistema pues tengo que instalar el template, he seguido el link pero me envia a la siguiente página: [Integration Services Product Samples](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=msftisprodsamples) el cual al darle clic donde me dice que descargue, solo me descarga un zip que no le encuentro sentido y más que nada no contiene el archivo que me promete, les agradeceria la ayuda para saber el punto exacto de descarga del archivo o del template que me pide para poder continuar con el tutorial.

Comment: ahi dice que hagas click en el zip y lo abras. lo abriste?

Comment: si pero me trae puras carpetas y ninguna con el tipo de archivo que me pide :(